# Complexity of $x+\log x+\log(\log x)+...+\log(\log(\log(...(\log x)...)))$

Tags: calculus, computational-complexity

Formally, we define a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ such that $f_0(x) = x$ and $f_{a+1}(x) = \log(f_a(x))$.

What is $$\text{O}\left(\sum_{i=0}^n f_i(n)\right)?$$

Comment: Do you really mean $i$ run from $0$ to $x$?

Comment: Yes, I defined f_0(x) = x, it might also be interesting to see the case where i starts at 1, but I don't need to know it currently

Comment: ALso, I guess you meant $f_{a+1}(x)=\log(f_a(x))$

Comment: I am asking for the end $x$. It may be better to write $\lfloor x\rfloor$.

Comment: Yes, I reedited the question

Comment: Yes, it is probably a good idea to change x to n so it would be clear I mean for it to be discrete

Comment: What is the context of this problem?

Comment: I thought of an implementation of the BigInt data structure, and I want to know what is the space complexity of my implementation

Comment: [Relevant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm).

Comment: Now, is $n$ a given fixed natural number? Or $\lfloor x\rfloor$. If $n$ is fixed, then the answer is obviously $O(x)$.

Comment: n is not fixed, there was a typo in the question

Comment: Very rough estimate is $O(n^2)$, but I suspect you need a more accurate one. Is, for example, $O(n+n\log n)$ enough good?

Comment: I hoped for the more accurate one, but this is good enough for my purposes

Comment: More accurate $O(n\log\log n)$ . Composition can be taken fixed amount times.

Comment: Yea obviously for every fixed a the complexity is $O(nf_a(n))$, but I was hoping to get a better upper bound if possible